# Does laziness for clojure hash-maps ever make sense?

Tags: clojure

I need to return a sequence, a number and a hash-map from my function (all wrapped in a vector) so that the printed return value looks like this:

```
[ ([:c :a] [:e :c] [:f :e] [:d :e] [:g :f] [:b :a])  15
  {:g :c, :f :a, :c :e, :d :a, :b :a, :c :a} ]
```

Since my inputs could be large, I'd like to return lazy sequences/objects from my function.
The sequence of pairs (the first object in my return vector) was easy enough to make lazy by wrapping 'lazy-seq' around the conj calls that build it up.

The hash-map (3rd object in my return vector and potentially very large like my sequence) is being built-up (using assoc calls) in the same loop-recur block as the sequence. The hash-map is additional info that some of my callers will use but if the pairs-sequence is returned as lazy then I'm wondering if it makes sense to send back a potentially huge hash-map with (an efficient) lazy-seq even if I make it an optional return-value. The entries in the hash-map are related to the pairs in the lazy-sequence.

So here is my noobie question: Is there any sense in sending back a lazy-sequence of MapEntry's in place of a large HashMap? That is, assuming a user would take a chunk of the lazy-seq of MapEntrys, convert them to hashmap to do a lookup..failing which they'd take the next chunk and so on. Is this a sensible way to lazily use associative-data?
Are there some idiomatic ways to return/manage large associative data in Clojure? 
Would appreciate any ideas as to what my options are. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, giving them a lazy map is not possible. A lazy sequence of MapEntries is possible, but not very useful. There are a number of other options that might make sense that are similar, though.

- You say the caller might not need the map at all: so return a *delay* of a map, which they can force if they need it.
- If the keys are cheap to compute, but the values are expensive, you can return a full map with the correct keys, and values which are each delays; the caller can force only the values they need.

You can still return a lazy-seq of vectors (I wouldn't bother with making them MapEntries), but there's basically no way the caller will be able to treat this as a lazy map. Either they only want to look up a fixed set of already-known keys (in which case they'll just lazily filter over the entries, never making it a map) or they want to look up entries arbitrarily, in which case they'll have to keep all the entries in memory after looking up the first entry, so that they can still look up the second, and so they might as well just dump the whole thing into a fully-realized map.

Comment: Thanks much for your ideas. The keys and the values are both equally cheap (both are keywords); there just may be a large number of them. The hash-map to be returned essentially contains pointers from one to the other. I am intrigued by your idea of a delay. Could you please elaborate how one could build a delay for a Map that is progressively being built up in a loop-recur block?
Do you mean this:
    `(loop [ my-map {} my-pairs [] ...]
        ...
       (recur (delay (assoc my-map k v))  ...))`

Comment: You can't (or at least I wasn't suggesting you should) progressively build the map in a delay. Just delay a building of the entire map: if they force it, they get the whole map. `(delay (loop [my-map {}] (if (...) (recur ...) my-map)))`.

Comment: OK. That will be a little tough to pull off as I build my lazy seq in the same loop-recur block.  But you've definitely given me something to work with.

Answer (score 2):

No, Clojure does not have lazy maps.

Also, if you are building up a sequence using loop/recur, I don't believe that trying to make it lazy accomplishes anything (unless generating each element is slow).

Look at these two functions:

```
(defn bad-lazy-range [begin end]
  (loop [i (dec end) lst nil]
    (if (>= i begin)
      (recur (dec i) (lazy-seq (cons i lst)))
      lst)))

(defn good-lazy-range [begin end]
  (if (>= begin end)
    nil
    (lazy-seq (cons begin (good-lazy-range (inc begin) end)))))
```

`bad-lazy-range` will recur `begin-end` times, generating a thunk (a lazy sequence link) each time, and then return the outermost thunk.  This thunk needs to keep the reference to the next thunk, which needs a reference to the third thunk, etc.  You do all the work immediately and generate a pseudo-linked list of thunks which takes up more space than a normal list would.

`good-lazy-range`, however, returns immediately without recursing more -- the recursive call is hidden inside the thunk and won't be evaluated until necessary.  This also prevents a stack overflow exception -- without the `lazy-seq` call, it could generate a stack overflow exception, but at each step, it evaluates one call to `good-lazy-range` and returns.  The caller can then evaluate the next call, but at this point, the stack frame from the first call is long gone.

In general, only use `lazy-seq` if you can wrap it around a significant amount of computation.  In the first function, it is only wrapped around a call to `cons`, which would return quickly anyway.  In the second function, however, it is wrapped around a call to `cons` and the recursive call, which means that it is delaying a worthwhile amount of computation.

If your code uses lazyness correctly and uses loop/recur, please post it -- I would be interested to see how you did it.

Comment: Thanks for your nice insight and the illustrative example. It makes sense. In your example the object being consed (lst) is rather small. On the other hand, if the object being consed was obtained as a result of significant computation then it would seem that it still makes sense to have the lazy-seq call like this (sorry it is not well-formatted):  

    `(loop [..  lst nil]  
        ..
        (if termination-condn-met?
            lst
            (recur ... (lazy-seq (cons x (reduce #(process-it % %2) my-large-map))))))`

Would you agree?

Comment: Yes - in this case, you are wrapping `lazy-seq` around a significant computation, so it is useful.  The important thing is not that `lazy-seq` is being wrapped around a recursive call, but that it is wrapped around a non-trivial computation.  Recursive calls are simply a common non-trivial computation.

Answer (score 0):

From the example you gave why return the map at all caller can just build the map from the seq using (into {} s)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The map cannot be built by the caller as the MapEntry pairs that define the map could be different from the pairs in the sequence. In my example above they just happen to be related in a similar manner. I mean :d and :a could be together in a MapEntry which is not a pair in the sequence. Also the order of the 2 values in the pair could be different. I'll fix my example to clarify that.

Comment: You could have two lazy sequences that could be built into maps by the caller